# How to call a props function without any eventHandler

Tags: reactjs

I'm learning react and stuck with one problem. While the button is clicked function3 gets called successfully however then it says that this.props.function is not a function. I even binded the function with this. However, not getting where I'm going wrong. Searched a lot on stackoverflow but none of them are targeting my queries.

```
  class Parent extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.function1 = this.function1.bind(this)
    }
    function1 = (someAttributes) =>{
        this.setState({
            //update the state
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <Child function={this.function1}/>
        )
    }
}


class Child extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.function2 = this.function2.bind(this)
        this.function3 = this.function3.bind(this) //tried this as well.
    }

    function2 = (someAttributes) =>{
        this.props.function(someAttributes)
    }

    function3 = () =>{
        //the logic
        this.function2(someAttributes)
    }
    
    render(){
        return(
           <Button onClick={this.function3}/>
           // even tried <Button onClick={()=>this.function3()}
        )
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Is this your code verbatim? You have `class Parent` twice. The second one should be `Child`, correct?

Comment: Typo, `this.function2.bind.this(this)` should be `this.function2.bind(this)`, but you shouldn't need to do this since you are using arrow functions, `this` is bound automagically for you. But I've also duplicated your code into a codesandbox and there're are other issues I'm working through. `someAttributes` is undefined, once I defined this your code appears to run. https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-call-a-props-function-withot-any-eventhandler-23nor?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese will update this as well in the question.

Comment: I think issue is unreproducible/caused by typo and suggest voting to close unless you've a compelling reason it's something else.

Comment: @NamrataSanger `function` is a reserved keyword in JavaScript, I would suggest not to use it as a `prop` name as you did in `<Child function={this.function1}/>`. Even if it works, we should treat it as a reserved keyword and not use as an identifier / name. I hope your problem is fixed as we closed the question marking as a *Typo*.

Comment: @AjeetShah yes in my actual program I'm not using this naming convention function. However, the code which "De C" provided I changed my code over there with proper naming conventions which I'm using in my actual code, and on codesandbox it works but not in my project.

Comment: If you can edit your question and provide a more accurate code representation (or even the actual code) that reproduces your issue that would be more beneficial to you and other readers later. If you also create a *running* codesandbox or similar that reproduces the issue that we could live debug in that would be really helpful. As-is it just seems to be a typo, but perhaps there is some detail we're missing that you haven't included in your snippets. Including any steps you are doing to reproduce the issue are welcome as well.

Comment: Thanks @DrewReese from your suggestion I was writing the code in the code pen and then found the error. I was actually passing the props from the super parent component and forgot to pass the props in the Parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.function2 = this.function2.bind.this(this);` should be `this.function2 = this.function2.bind(this);`

Everything else is working fine [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-leftpad-ngw6c?file=/src/App.js)

For simplicity I've used `console.log`. You can use `setState` if you want.

Comment: Hi @De C. I updated the code its my typing error. In the original code I'm using correct syntax for binding this.

Comment: It is working fine, You can see the sandbox link that I've added in my answer

Comment: Hi @De C I checked the code on the codeSandbox it works fine no idea why it's giving error in my application.

Comment: @NamrataSanger restart your ide and start the app again. Sometimes it causes because of cache stored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple way. You don't need define all these functions

```
class Parent extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}
function1 = (someAttributes) =>{
    this.setState({
        //update the state
    })
}
render(){
    return(
        <Child function={(...params) => this.function1(...params)}/>
    )
}
}


class Child extends Component{
constructor(props){
    super(props);
}

function2 = (someAttributes) =>{
    this.props.function(someAttributes)
}

function3 = () =>{
    //the logic
    this.function2(someAttributes)
}

render(){
    return(
       <Button onClick={() => this.function3()}/>
       // even tried <Button onClick={()=>this.function3()}
    )
}
}
```

Comment: Hi @Yadab actually that's what I'm not targeting. The function3 contains the entire business logic and I'm calling the props function inside it because I want to update the parent state.

Comment: @NamrataSanger is passing the `function3` as a prop in `Button ` component.

Comment: If you want to do that then in your parent function you can use arrow function. `<Child function={(...params) => this.function1(...params)}/>`

Comment: I have updated the code. You will get your desired output.

Answer (score 0):

You can use arrow functions, here is a working codesandbox example of your code. I alerted every step to your parent function:

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-playground-forked-p0iwv?file=/index.js)